# How to log when a div hits the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, console.log

I have got a Div on my page. And when that hits the top of the page it should output a console.log. This is my code so far but it doesn't work for me. Any Suggestions?
Thanks and Sorry for my bad English.

```
  var distance = $('.img').offset().top;
    $window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
        console.log("Div is now at the top of the site!")
    }
});
```

And this is my HTML part:

```
<div class="img">
        <img src="city.jpg">
        </div>
```

Comment: Your code works.... https://jsfiddle.net/okct6z6p/

Comment: It's working. What's the problem here?

Comment: I still get this error in Chrome: "script.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at script.js:1
(anonymous) @ script.js:1"

Comment: The code is working in Chrome too. There must be something else you are not telling us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get the position of an element in relation to the viewport. See the example I've added. It will log how many pixels the div is from the top of the viewport when you scroll the document.

When doing work on scroll it is always a good idea to debounce the work you want to do. See here for more information: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

```js
const
  contentDiv = document.getElementById('content-div');
  
function onScrollHandler(event) {
  console.log(`Pixels from top: ${contentDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top}`);  
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler);
```

```css
.vertical-space {
  height: 200vh;
}

.content-div {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-space"></div>
<div id="content-div" class="vertical-space content-div">Now you see me</div>
```

Comment: I still get this error : script.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null
    at onScrollHandler (script.js:14)
onScrollHandler @ script.js:14

Comment: Do you mean in my answer or did you copy & paste the answer into your own code?

Comment: Even when I copy your code one to one it still gives me that error.

Comment: My example uses different class names than your code, it won't work without some light modifications.

Comment: I did change the class names. And even when I take your code one to one I still get this error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null"

Comment: Is the div with image added to the page after loading the document? Is your script tag in the head rather than just before closing the body?

Comment: got it to work finally. var
  contentDiv = document.getElementById('img');
  
function onScrollHandler(event) {
 contentDiv = document.getElementById('img');
  console.log('Pixels from top: ' + contentDiv.getBoundingClientRect().top);  
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', onScrollHandler);     this worked for me